# 'Add Service' Disabled on Ambari 1.6.0 Sandbox

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm experimenting with Ambari in the Hortonworks sandbox, and have hit a roadblock. When trying to add kafka in order to do real time processing, the 'Add Service' dropdown in Ambari is disabled. It seems to be a known bug. I followed the fix suggestion here: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.5.1.0/bk_releasenotes_ambari_1.5.1/content/ch_relnotes-ambari-1.5.1.0-knownissues.html, which completed, but did not fix the issue. After that, I tried upgrading my version of Ambari from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0, which also completed, but similarly did not fix the issue. I have restarted my VM, cleared the cache on my browser, and seem to have run out of options.

Is there anything else I can try to get this working?

Comment: lark please post answer if you got it....even i m dealing with the same situation ... and ill do the same if ill get any work around.

Comment: I ended up giving up on the sandbox, and installing all components separately on a linux distro. They're supposed to have a new sandbox out Q1 next year, perhaps that will fix it.